# Casting int to str in cython?

Tags: string, cython

I have a very simple question on how to cast an int to string in Cython. I wish to concatenate a variable number to a phrase, e.g.

```
cdef str consPhrase = "attempt"
cdef int number = 7     #variable
cdef str newString = consPhrase + <str>number    #so it should be "attempt7", "attempt8", etc.
```

However, I keep getting an error claiming

```
TypeError: Expected str, got int
```

I've looked on how to cast in Cython, and it claims that it is down with the < > brackets, so why isn't the int being converted into the str?

I've even tried

```
cdef str makeStr(str l):
    return l


cdef str consPhrase = "attempt"
cdef int number = 7
cdef str newString = consPhrase + makeStr(number)
```

but it throws the same error on the same line (the `cdef str newString = consPhrase + makeStr(number)` line). So, what is the most efficient and correct way of doing this simple task? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just to convert the data to a string, just like you would in any other python code:

```
cdef str newString = consPhrase + str(number)
```

Casting like you are trying to do won't work because `str` is a Python type which maps to `bytes` in Python2 and `unicode` in Python3. Since it might be a unicode string, there's no safe way to cast an integer to a string like you're trying to do.